# How to push mat-list-items to the bottom without using absolute position in Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have just started using Angular Material and I wanted to implement the sidenav to have items that are at the bottom of the page. For now I am able to accomplish it with css.

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Is there any way to put spaces between items? My issue comes when I resize the page, the bottom items overlap with the items which are above.

I've included screenshots and the code below. Thanks.

[image: Full screen window]

[image: Resized window]

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="h-screen w-screen">
<mat-sidenav #sidenav class="shadow border-0" fixedInViewport mode="side" opened>  
    <mat-toolbar>
        <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="navigation.toggle()">
            <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-fire" aria-label="SLMC Logo"></mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item>
            <button mat-icon-button>
                <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-users-cog" aria-label="Administrator"></mat-icon>
            </button>
        </a>
        <a mat-list-item>
            <button mat-icon-button>
                <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-tachometer-alt" aria-label="Services"></mat-icon>
            </button>
        </a>
        <a mat-list-item>
            <button mat-icon-button>
                <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-chart-bar" aria-label="Analytics"></mat-icon>
            </button>
        </a>
        <a mat-list-item>
            <button mat-icon-button>
                <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-plus" aria-label="Compose"></mat-icon>
            </button>
        </a>

        <!-- This is where the bottom items reside.-->
        <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0"> 
            <a mat-list-item>
                <button mat-icon-button>
                    <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-bell" aria-label="Notifications"></mat-icon>
                </button>
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item>
                <button mat-icon-button>
                    <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-user" aria-label="User Account"></mat-icon>
                </button>
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item>
                <button mat-icon-button>
                    <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-cog" aria-label="Settings"></mat-icon>
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-sidenav-container>
        <mat-sidenav #navigation class="shadow border-0" fixedInViewport mode="side" opened>
            <app-navigation (toggleNavigation)="navigation.toggle()"></app-navigation>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content class="page-wrap">
            <app-header></app-header>
            <main class="flex-1">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </main>
            <app-footer></app-footer>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very interesting and logical question... getting the bottom 3 icons to stick to the bottom requires `position:absolute`, which causes the over-riding effect (which is exactly the effect which is expected with absolute positioning).

To get our ideal scenario, we gotta toggle the `position:relative` between `position:absolute` based on the breakpoint where the over-riding starts to take effect. This is where we needed JavaScript/TypeScript as CSS can't do this alone...

You can check [complete working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5xrzu)

this is the relevant **TS** file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HostListener} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Sidenav open & close behavior */
@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-open-close-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-open-close-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-open-close-example.css'],
})
export class SidenavOpenCloseExample {
  events: string[] = [];
  opened: boolean;
  appropriateClass:string = '';

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  getScreenHeight(event?){
    //console.log(window.innerHeight);
    if(window.innerHeight<=412){
      this.appropriateClass = 'bottomRelative';
    }else{
      this.appropriateClass = 'bottomStick';
    }
  }
  constructor(){
    this.getScreenHeight();
  }

  shouldRun = [/(^|\.)plnkr\.co$/, /(^|\.)stackblitz\.io$/].some(h => h.test(window.location.host));
}
```

note the *ngClass* in the relevant **HTML** below:

```
  <mat-nav-list>
        <div class=""> 
          <a mat-list-item>
              <button mat-icon-button>
                  <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-users-cog" aria-label="Administrator"></mat-icon>
              </button>
          </a>
          <a mat-list-item>
              <button mat-icon-button>
                  <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-tachometer-alt" aria-label="Services"></mat-icon>
              </button>
          </a>
          <a mat-list-item>
              <button mat-icon-button>
                  <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-chart-bar" aria-label="Analytics"></mat-icon>
              </button>
          </a>
          <a mat-list-item>
              <button mat-icon-button>
                  <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-plus" aria-label="Compose"></mat-icon>
              </button>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- This is where the bottom items reside.-->
          <div [ngClass]='appropriateClass'> 
              <a mat-list-item>
                  <button mat-icon-button>
                      <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-bell" aria-label="Notifications"></mat-icon>
                  </button>
              </a>
              <a mat-list-item>
                  <button mat-icon-button>
                      <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-user" aria-label="User Account"></mat-icon>
                  </button>
              </a>
              <a mat-list-item>
                  <button mat-icon-button>
                      <mat-icon inline=true fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-cog" aria-label="Settings"></mat-icon>
                  </button>
              </a>
          </div>

    </mat-nav-list>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
button {border:1px solid red}
.bottomStick{/*border-top:1px solid green;border-bottom:1px solid green;*/position:absolute; bottom:0}
.bottomRelative{position:relative;}
```

Comment: thanks. that sure solved my problem when opening the app on the phone. i really didnt think of that. i'm new to angular. just want to try things out. thanks by the way.

Answer (score 6):

I use flex-layout and manage to add an empty element between items.
There is no CSS added.
The container needs to have 100% height and in my case, I have to add FxFill, you can manage the way you like.

// sidenav-componet

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFill>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z5">
    <h2 >Menu</h2>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-list  fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
    <mat-list-item fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
      <h4 routerLink="/">Home</h4>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-list-item fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
      <h4 routerLink="/admin">Admin</h4>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>

    <span fxFlex></span>

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-list-item fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
      <h4 (click)="logout()">Logout</h4>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  </mat-list>
</div>
```